# atom live server console refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I am working with Atom Live Server, every time I execute it the same error appears, how can I refresh my console, this is the error that appears

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at (index):10

I get the same error with every file I execute with Atom Live Server

[image]

Comment: click on `(index):10` (on the right side) to see where does it come from

Comment: Show the code from line 10 :)

Comment: https://ibb.co/doLU7Q

Comment: The code is in this link